# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" while reading blob fields

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a little website that gets pic from a mysql DB (BLOB field) and then i print them on my webpages.

With some classes i read the blob fields, i check the pics dimensions, if necessary i resize them and with a servlet i print the pics on my pages.

In every pages i do it (read some blob fields, check the sizes, resize and print several pics).

Each pics saved inside the DB is less then 200 kb.

I read the blob field this way:

1)InputStream photo =  record.getBinaryStream("blob_field_name");

2) BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read(photo);

3) i resize the pics

I get often this message on tomcat's LOG `"Exception in thread "http-bio-12418-exec-26" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"`

I have my own virtual machine on a server that i rented, and i have 64 mb of heap space.

If i check the heap i have this result (for the same page with the same pics):

- heapsize on my laptop  293404672
- heapsize on the server 503316480

How can i know if i made mistakes in my code or if it is a server problems?

Thank you

Comment: Are you closing the streams?

Comment: Don't read the full file in memory.

Comment: I think i closed all the stream. I checked it several times.

Comment: @AmanArora what do u mean with "Don't read the full file in memory"?

Comment: Share your code where you are reading file?

Comment: Is the stack-trace identical in every log file occurrence?

Comment: What (file)size do your images have?

Comment: I created a page almost empy. I just print out the heapsize, and it's always about 503316480, almost the same heapsize i get in other pages, even those with pics

Answer (score 1):

Don't read blobs into memory. The whole idea is that they are too big for normal processing. Just read its input stream and write it to the output. If you need extra metadata about the blob with as it's size, store it in another column.

Comment: I edited my post, adding the code i use to read a blob field. can u take a look? Thank you

Comment: You should serve the images direct to the output on demand via `<img>` URLs. There's no reason to be loading them into memory at the server, and especially not to construct them as images.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
```

Note that some users have reported that the double quotes give problems, hence you might want to use:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

EDIT:

Since you are using Tomcat, use this:

Open up tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

```
add this line to the JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Save and exit , restart Tomcat

Comment: it seems to have the same problem. i also created a page almost empy. I just print out the heapsize, and it's always about 503316480

Answer (score 0):

Use some memory monitoring (you can start with jVisualVM) and automated tests (Selenium, jMeter). Look for memory consumption, garbage collections and memory leaks. You can increase the heap size, but this can be only temporary solution, if you hava some leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Heap size does not reflect "How much memory am I using", it reflects "How much memory does the JVM have in total to use".

You Mention in your question that "each pic is less than 200kb". That's irrelevant. You are loading it into an ImageBuffer, and the buffer doesn't care that your compressed JPEG file is less than 200kb. It is going to need at least 4 bytes pr. pixel in the image. This means that even a small 80x80 gravatar style image is 25Kb of memory. This is for each image you have. Since you are re-sizing this you need twice as much (one buffer for the source, one for the destination). Since you are handling multiple requests you need to further multiply by the amount of concurrent requests.

So you end up having to use quite a few resources. I think a better design would be to scale the images up-front, and store both versions, then serve either version as a stream (that is, don't load them into memory).

Comment: So, u suggest me to save different sizes of any image in the database? I didnt do it, because i wanted to be free to change the size of the images shown on my pages. That's why i saved just one big photos, that i resize in every page (i need at least 3 different sizes of every image). But maybe your solution is the right one, probably i have to change some of my code and of my logic.

Comment: Yes. Storage is generally speaking cheaper than memory and processing cycles. :)